# Fit all the children of WrapPanel with no scroll bars

Tags: wpf

I want to add images to WrapPanel and I want to see all of them without scrolling. I am resizing the images when new child added.
I have a class which inherits from `WrapPanel` and Resize() will be fired when child added. Here is the code:

```
    public void Resize()
    {
        int c = this.Children.Count;
        int d = 1;
        if (c <= 4 && c>1) d = 2;
        else if (c <= 9 && c>4) d = 3;
        else if (c <= 16 && c > 9) d = 4;

        foreach (UIElement child in this.Children)
        {
            dynamic ctrl = child;
            ctrl.Width = this.Width / d;
        }
    }
```

Is this the best approach?

Comment: How about using `UniformGrid`, that way you only have to set the amount of Rows/Columns based on the count of images you have, and it will scale them all to fit.

Comment: I like it. Thanks sa_ddam213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sa_ddam213 gave me the idea of using `UniformGrid`. That solved my problem. I am answering to my own question to make this question as "Answered".